# Match and merge info between arrays Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I get a list of contacts from the server with the following attributes:

- phone
- name
- connected

From the device, I get the contacts' profile photo (the server doesn't have it), which results in an object with this info:

- phone
- name
- thumbnail

My goal is to have a single list with all the info merged. Each object should be like this:

- phone
- name
- thumbnail
- connected

Right now, it works, and the code looks like this:

```
   var itemsResult: [Contact] = []
       for var item in listFromDevice {
           if let itemFromServer = listFromServer.filter({ $0.phone == item.phone }).first {
               item.connected = itemFromServer.connected
               itemsResult.append(item)
           }
       }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it? I read about the `zip` and `map` functions but I'm not sure on how to apply them in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to find an object by its attribute is to start with a Dictionary with the attribute as the key. If the array order is important to you, the value in the Dictionary can be the index into the array.

Here's a generalized example:

```
struct S {
    let id : Int
}
let arr : [S] = [S(id:1328), S(id:43), S(id:2)]
```

Start by arming yourself with the requisite dictionary:

```
var d = [Int:Int]()
for pair in arr.enumerated() {
    d[pair.element.id] = pair.offset
}
```

Now lookup by id into the array is extremely efficient and direct:

```
let idToFind = 43
if let ix = d[idToFind] {
    let s = arr[ix]
    print(s.id) // 43, we found the right one
}
```